# Find logs of requests that are longer than 1000ms using regex

Tags: regex, google-cloud-logging

I'm using regex to search Google Cloud Logs for requests that are longer than 1000ms

Here are some example requests:

```
{
    ...
    textPayload: "GET /getUser 200 - - 5380.879 ms",
    ...
}
{
    ...
    textPayload: "GET /getUser 200 - - 34.879 ms",
    ...
}
```

Here is the search I'm using:

```
textPayload =~ "^(GET)|(POST).*[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|\d{4,}(\sms)$"
```

I only want to return the one that ends with a value of over `1000.000 ms` but my regex doesn't seem to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
textPayload =~ "^(?:GET|POST).* ([1-9]\d{3,}(?:\.\d+)?)\sms$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ozAQyR/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:GET|POST)` - `GET` or `POST`
- `.*`  - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a space
- `([1-9]\d{3,}(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: a non-zero digit, then three or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and then one or more digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `ms` - `ms` string
- `$` - end of string.